# Layout Gravity in Android TextView widgets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to do something very simple: create a label in the middle of the screen.  But I tried every combination of layout_gravity and it just doesn't work.  The text 'My Cool Apps' is always on the right side of the screen.  I want it to be in the center.  This is the part of main.xml that does the label:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Cool Apps"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone help with this?  Why is the above not working, and how can I make it work?

Comment: What does the rest of your layout look like?  FYI, there is layout_gravity and gravity.  Layout_gravity affects the layout.  gravity affects the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Cool Apps"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This worked for me.  And that's good.  But I don't exactly know why.  If I change layout_gravity to gravity, then it doesn't work.  What's the difference between layout_gravity and gravity?

Comment: Nevermind, I found two good web pages on this: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/ and http://sandipchitale.blogspot.com/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to play with RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Cool Apps"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm going to stick with LinearLayout for now (too much to learn all at once!)

Answer (score 1):

you can try changing your code with the following code:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="My Cool Apps" >
</EditText>
```

I hope that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one you will get it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That also works.  I'm not sure which answer I like better: yours or Andras.  But both work and Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Layout_gravity will be used for views and edittext.gravity will be used for layout's.